# AWS DynamoDB Local add global secondary index using awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

Hello I try to execute the following command in order to add a Global Secondary Index to an existing table:

```
aws dynamodb update-table \
    --region eu-west-1 \
    --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:8000/ \
    --table-name ssib_dev_assetsTable \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=AssetGroup,AttributeType=S \
    --global-secondary-index-updates  \
    Create="{IndexName=gsi_group,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=AssetGroup,KeyType=HASH}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}}" \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10 \
```

After + or - 10seconds I have the following response, without any explicit error message. I use https://hub.docker.com/r/cnadiminti/dynamodb-local/ to emulate my db.

> An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the UpdateTable
> operation (reached max retries: 9): The request processing has failed
> because of an unknown error, exception or failure.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the `--region eu-west-1` option?

Comment: nothing change.

Comment: DynamoDB Local is actually running, yes?

Comment: yes with no problem

Comment: FYI the docs indicate that the endpoint URL should be http://localhost:8000 so please test that to be sure it’s not as simple as that.

Comment: I already created my table with `aws dynamodb create-table ..... --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:8000/ .....` which works. I tested to be sure with localhost:8000 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `--global-secondary-index-updates` should be a valid JSON string, which it is not in your case. It is also missing a mandatory key, `ProvisionedThroughput`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-table.html

Here goes:

```
aws dynamodb update-table \
    --region eu-west-1 \
    --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:8000 \
    --table-name ssib_dev_assetsTable \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=AssetGroup,AttributeType=S \
    --global-secondary-index-updates '[{"Create":{"IndexName":"gsi_group","KeySchema":[{"AttributeName":"AssetGroup","KeyType":"HASH"}],"Projection":{"ProjectionType":"ALL"},"ProvisionedThroughput":{"ReadCapacityUnits":5,"WriteCapacityUnits":5}}}]'

By the way, you should probably use the official image instead of some image by some random user docker user: https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly it's a little strange that on some legacy commands I got things like `IndexName=gsi_name_parent,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=GroupName,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=GroupParent,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=ALL},ProvisionedThroughput={ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=10}" \` and it works. At least only json is clear.